# Xamarin.Android Project : ViewPager in a fragment shows blank

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my project, I have some Fragment layouts.

In Main.axml, I use CoordinatorLayout and NavigationView to navigate to my layouts. That's no problem. But in one Fragment, I want to use TabLayout and ViewPager to show two sub layouts, which is also Fragment, I have problem. When I switch the TabLayout, ViewPager shows blank.

In short, ViewPager inside a Fragment and ViewPager has nothing in it.

I debugged for two days and searched many ways to solve this question, but useless. Here are my partial code.

Thanks in advance

[Interface Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2NEB.png)

Fragment layout has ViewPager

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/astroTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/astroViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Its Fragment code

```
class AstroFragment : Fragment
        {
            ViewPager astroViewPager;
            TabLayout astroTabLayout;

            public override void OnStart()
            {
                base.OnStart();
            }

            public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            }

            public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);           
            }

            public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AstroFragment, container, false);

                astroViewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.astroViewPager);
                astroTabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.astroTabLayout);

                MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager);
                astroViewPager.Adapter = adapter;
                astroViewPager.SetCurrentItem(0, true);
                astroViewPager.OffscreenPageLimit = 2;

                astroTabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(astroViewPager);

                return view;
            }
        }
```

One sub Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="30px">
    <TextView
        android:text="data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

One sub Fragment code

```
class AstroDataFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AstroDataFragment, container, false);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

MyFragmentPagerAdapter code

```
class MyFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        const int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
        private string[] tabTitles = { "视图一", "网页图表" };
        private List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
        {
            // Sub Fragments
            fragments.Add(new AstroDataFragment());
            fragments.Add(new AstroImageFragment());                
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return PAGE_COUNT;
            }
        }

        public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object @object)
        {
            //base.DestroyItem(container, position, @object);
        }

        public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return fragments[position];
        }

        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            var charSequence = CharSequence.ArrayFromStringArray(tabTitles);

            return charSequence[position];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are your internal fragments (`AstroDataFragment` and `AstroImageFragment`) also overriding `OnCreateView`? It looks like their views are never being inflated individually.

Comment: I added one sub fragment code

Comment: Can you give me the github link of your demo? When I creat taplayout will meet some issue.

Comment: Can you provide sub-fragment XMLs?

Comment: I added one sub fragment layout code, but it has nothing, I didn't add any controls, just a text to show what fragment